# How do I make my url to look nicer?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using this https://github.com/panique/mini

If I have an URL that looks like this

```
http://domain.com/aaaa/index/b5b31f4d-0ac3-4419-b620-d5bc034717db
```

I would like to shorten the link. If the user visits the link

```
http://domain.com/b5b31f4d-0ac3-4419-b620-d5bc034717db
```

or at least remove the index

```
http://domain.com/aaaa/b5b31f4d-0ac3-4419-b620-d5bc034717db
```

Should the user arrive to content of this page

```
http://domain.com/aaaa/index/b5b31f4d-0ac3-4419-b620-d5bc034717db

b5b31f4d-0ac3-4419-b620-d5bc034717db is a random value for the user.
```

I have tested different versions of

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_])/?$    aaaa/index/$1    [NC,L]
```

^ my domain

after that is can be a random number 0-9 and a-z `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Change it to aaaa/index/myRandomNumber

Comment: you need to use .htaccess rules to modify your url

Comment: I know that but not how (what I should have in my .htaccess)

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ , hope it helps.

Comment: You need to write RewriteRules for the rewriting your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)+)$ /aaaa/index/$1 [NC,L]
```

The restriction of the pattern is intentional, in order to not rewrite each non-existing file/folder